# Disable logging from audioplayers library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

Hey I keep getting this annoying output in my console from this library:
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

I used the following function and thought it would stop the logs:
`AudioPlayer.global.changeLogLevel(LogLevel.none);`

But I still keep getting this and more:

"method: setVolume"
"playerId: AUDIO_PLAYER_ID"
"method: setSourceUrl"
"playerId: AUDIO_PLAYER_ID"
"method: resume"
"playerId: AUDIO_PLAYER_ID"

The only functions I am using are those two:

`await player.stop();`
`await player.play(AssetSource(asset), volume: 1);`

Any way of disabling the logs that I am missing?